# Render mesh with level curves

Tags: shaders

With the geometry node, I can retrieve the z coordinate for use in shading. Also, I can use map range, truncate, and divide, to "posterize". Is it possible to produce level curves, that is what would happen if you used some kind of edge detection after posterization.

An example of a function surface with level curves on the texture:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a reference or sample of the effect you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @user877329: pls do not link images but copy/paste them directly in the questions. thx. One reason for this is, if the content of the link "dies", your whole question is useless for others. The second reason is that you "directly" can read your question without having to click on links.

Comment: You can find a shader solution [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/212767/35559)

Comment: @RobinBetts: wow...another genius answer from you...Chapeau!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this node setup:

[image]

to get this:

[image]

The basic idea is just using boolean mesh operations as planes, use the result and convert it to a curve and add a color.

another node setup (which is more stable because mesh boolean is making often trouble):

[image]

Raycast is much more stable:

[image]

[image]