# Replicating similar texture procedurally in Alfie Garland's piece "Canyon"

Tags: shaders, procedural, npr

Is there a way to use a combination of Blender's procedural nodes to replicate this wavy/rigid texture style found in Alfie Garland's work for use in an NPR shader?

https://www.artstation.com/artwork/nQvmxe

[image]

I'm focusing mainly on the unique lines and simple distortion Alfie uses in this amazing landscape style.

[image]

Comment: The wave node and a color ramp might be your friend here. But this scene might also involve the proper user of the lineart renderer. Or simply use proper textures. Or draw it with grease pencil. Several approaches possible.

Comment: Is [this](https://imgur.com/a/p459vgh) close?  I don't know ... maybe a bit wavy. The strata in the ref have a more angular tilt, which has a 1960's feel...

Comment: @RobinBetts Wow, that looks good! Closer than I've come for sure. I feel as though it would be possible to get that angular tilt, but the right combination of math nodes, textures, and mapping is beyond me. A wave texture set to triangle seems to get the closest results. But the distortion bends it quite a bit. That 1960s feel is exactly what I'm going for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach might give you a good start.

First job, get some tilting strata-lines, at randomish intervals up Z, slicing through the mesh in XY:

[image]

- A 1D Voronoi gives us random width bands, each with their own XY UV.
- Lines are drawn into the UV-cells, by taking a delta threshold on the dot product of the cell UV coordinate with a given (perpendicular) vector
- The lines are randomly tilted per-band, within given limits.
- But, since they are going to be projected through a 3D surface, the line thickness has to be corrected according to the surface normal, in a similar way to [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/212767/35559)

This group can be used in some way like this:

[image]

- A *Shader to RGB* node divides the light response of the surface into 2 bands; light/dark.
- The Strata lines invert the light/dark mask, so, as in your reference, you have shadow-color lines on lit surfaces, and vice-versa
- The whole Object Texture-Space is tilted and randomized by *Noise*, before use. This lets you introduce a little curl ( Multiply, and *Noise* settings) and overall tilt (Add)

I've found that variations are quite easy to create, and not bad for control...

[image]

Improvements might include deciding on a style for 3-level light-dark banding, overlaying object-shadows.

[image]

Comment: @bitblox  Thanks for the vote of confidence! This is almost there, IMO. I'm fascinated by how just tilting a few lines against one another makes that 1960's Hanna-Barbera feel. It's everywhere.. printed fabrics, lampshades, engraved drinking-glasses...